# Regex to split a string only by the last whitespace character

Tags: php, regex, string, split

hopefully this should be a quick and simple one, using PHP I'm trying to split a string into an array but by only the last instance of whitespace. So far I have...

```
$str="hello this is     a    space";
$arr=preg_split("/\s+/",$str);
print_r($arr);

Array ( [0] => hello [1] => this [2] => is [3] => a [4] => space )
```

...which splits by all instances of whitespace.

How can I expand this regular expression to split by only the last instance of whitespace? To become...

```
Array ( [0] => hello this is     a [1] => space )
```

Thank you in advance of your help!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try:

```
$arr=preg_split("/\s+(?=\S*+$)/",$str);
```

---

**Edit**

A short explanation:

The `(?= ... )` is called a positive [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). For example, `a(?=b)` will only match a single `'a'` if the next character (the one to the right of it) is a `'b'`. Note that the `'b'` is *not* a part of the match!

The `\S` is just a short-hand for the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^\s]`. In other words: it matches a single character other than a white space character. The `+` after the `*` makes the character class `\S` [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Finally, the `$` denotes the end of the string.

To recap, the complete regex `\s+(?=\S*+$)` would read in plain English as follows:

> match one or more white space characters only when looking ahead of those white space characters zero or more characters other than white space characters, followed by the end of the string, can be seen.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou, that works perfectly.

Just for understanding, could you explain how the '(?=\S*+$)' part of that expression work please?

Comment: That's great Bart, thankyou. I'd give you more points if I could!

Comment: I could make it work only when I removed the + or the * in your formula. I understand that possession attribute is not available in JavaScript ! But it really helped. Thanks

Comment: I had never heard of possesive before -- its totally awesome..  And your split expression is awesome too.

Comment: In which case would it not work when we left the `$` away?

Comment: @Adam in the case there is more than 1 space like this: `"a b c"`, which will be split into `["a", "b", "c"]` instead of `["a b", "c"]`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$str="hello this is a  space";

preg_match('~^(.*)\s+([^\s]+)$~', $str, $matches);
$result = array($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

You could do it without a regex:

```
$parts = array_map('trim', explode(' ', $str));
$result = array(
    implode(' ', array_slice($parts, 0, -1)),
    end($parts)
);
```

or

```
$lastSpace = strrpos($str, ' ');
$str1 = trim(substr($str, 0, $lastSpace));
$str2 = trim(substr($str, $lastSpace));
$result = array( $str1, $str2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `*` and `+` after `\S` dupicated? Only `/\s+(?=\S+$)/` or `/\s+(?=\S*$)/` is enough depends on the need.

Comment: Not duplicated - the `*+` is a single command, and `\S*+` can often be more efficient than doing `\S*`. Read up on "possessive quantifiers" for more details.

Comment: The possessive quantifier in this case makes no difference to pattern accuracy or pattern performance.  The whitespace quantifier is already greedily matching and the non-whitespace quantifier is also already greedily matching.  There is no benefit to explicitly calling for possessive matching.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you input string will have some non-whitespace character before the last occurring whitespace, you can use greedy matching, then reset the fullstring match so that the multiple spaces are consumed in the explosion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NbvW7))

```
$str = "hello this is     a    space";

var_export(
    preg_split('/.*\S\K +/', $str)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'hello this is     a',
  1 => 'space',
)
```

On the sample string, `/\s+(?=\S*$)/` takes 76 to match the targeted whitespaces and `.*\S\K +` takes just [25 steps](https://regex101.com/r/7mx7e4/1).