# Explode string on second last and last space to create exactly 3 elements

Tags: php, split, limit, explode, text-parsing

I want to split a space-delimited string by its spaces, but I need the total elements in the result array to be exactly 3 AND if the string has more than two spaces, only the last two spaces should be used as delimiters.

My input strings follow a predictable format.  The strings are one or more words, then a word, then a parenthetically wrapped word (word in this context is a substring with no whitespaces in it).

Sample strings:

1. `Stack Over Flow Abcpqr (UR)`
   becomes:
   `["Stack Over Flow", "Abcpqr", "(UR)"]`
2. `Fluency in English Conversation Defklmno (1WIR)`
   becomes:
   `["Fluency in English Conversation","Defklmno","(1WIR)"]`
3. `English Proficiency GHI (2WIR)`
   becomes:
   `["English Proficiency","GHI","(2WIR)"]`
4. `Testing ADG (3WIR)`
   becomes:
   `["Testing","ADG","(3WIR)"]`

I used the following code, but it is only good for `Testing (3WIR)`.

```
$Original = $row['fld_example'];                                    
$OriginalExplode = explode(' ', $Original);

<input name="example0" id="example0" value="<?php echo $OriginalExplode[0]; ?>" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>

<input name="example1" id="example1" value="<?php echo $OriginalExplode[1]; ?>" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Basically, I just need to explode the string on spaces, starting from the end of the string, and limiting the total explosions to 2 (to make 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this using `explode` and `str_replace`

```
$string = "Testing (3WIR)";
$stringToArray = explode(":",str_replace("(",":(",$string));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($stringToArray);
```

Edited question answer:-

```
$subject = "Fluency in English Conversation Defklmno (1WIR)";
$toArray = explode(' ',$subject);
if(count($toArray) > 2){
  $first       = implode(" ",array_slice($toArray, 0,count($toArray)-2));
  $second      = $toArray[count($toArray)-2];
  $third       = $toArray[count($toArray)-1];
  $result      = array_values(array_filter([$first, $second, $third]));
}else{
  $result = array_values(array_filter(explode(":",str_replace("(",":(",$subject))));
}
```

[DEMO HERE](https://3v4l.org/5HuOP)

Comment: Haha, thank you. I was just looking for something to split by the last space, and came across that regex answer. People here are in love with them, and it suited the question. But your answer is readable and understandable, and therefore better. If you want to be amused [read this](https://hackernoon.com/for-the-love-of-jeez-stop-using-regex-in-software-3a916e2c5987). That's what I think about regex's.

Comment: Now it is not so nice anymore... 

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you can suggest a better approach

Comment: Without a regular expression? Sure. I added it to my answer. You however detect the `(`, and I don't do that.

Comment: I find that hackernoon opinion piece to be unconstructive and inaccurate.  I am embarrassed that the author has these views as late as 2017.  How sad to push the agenda that regex only poisons software and makes it insecure.  Absolutely irresponsible and unfounded.  I kept shaking my head in disgust and eventually stopped reading before the end.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of regular expressions, but this one seems to work very fine:

[Regex to split a string only by the last whitespace character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530883/regex-to-split-a-string-only-by-the-last-whitespace-character)

So the PHP code would be:

```
function splitAtLastWord($sentence)
{
    return preg_split("/\s+(?=\S*+$)/", $sentence);
}

$sentence = "Fluency in English Conversation Defklmno (1WIR)";  

list($begin, $end)    = splitAtLastWord($sentence);
list($first, $middle) = splitAtLastWord($begin);
$result = [$first, $middle, $end]; 

echo "<pre>" . print_r($result, TRUE) . "</pre>";
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Fluency in English Conversation
    [1] => Defklmno
    [2] => (1WIR)
)
```

You can also write the same function without a regular expression:

```
function splitAtLastWord($sentence)
{
    $words = explode(" ", $sentence);
    $last  = array_pop($words);
    return [implode(" ", $words), $last];
}
```

Which is, to be honest, a better way of doing this.

This is a computationally more efficient way to do it:

```
function splitAtLastWord($sentence)
{
   $lastSpacePos = strrpos($sentence, " ");
   return [substr($sentence, 0, $lastSpacePos), substr($sentence, $lastSpacePos + 1)]; 
}
```

It looks a bit less nice but it is faster.

Anyway, defining a separate function like this is useful, you can reuse it in other places.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the two delimiting spaces, use `/ (?=(?:\S+ )?\()/` which leverages a lookahead containing an optional group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gnCFU))

```
$strings = [
    'Stack Over Flow Abcpqr (UR)',
    'Fluency in English Conversation Defklmno (1WIR)',
    'English Proficiency GHI (2WIR)',
    'Testing ADG (3WIR)',
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo json_encode(
             preg_split('/ (?=(?:\S+ )?\()/', $string)
         ) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
["Stack Over Flow","Abcpqr","(UR)"]
["Fluency in English Conversation","Defklmno","(1WIR)"]
["English Proficiency","GHI","(2WIR)"]
["Testing","ADG","(3WIR)"]
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
             #match a literal space
(?=          #start lookahead
  (?:\S+ )?  #optionally match one or more non-whitespaces followed by a space
  \(         #match a literal opening parenthesis 
)            #end lookahead
```

When matching the first delimiting space, the optional subpattern will match characters.  When matching the second delimiting space (before the parenthesis), the optional subpattern will not match any characters.

---

As a more generic solution, if the goal was to split on the space before either of the last two non-whitespace substrings, this pattern looks ahead in the same fashion but matches all the way to the end of the string.

```
/ (?=(?:\S+ )?\S+$)/
```

---

While I don't find non-regex solutions to be anywhere near as elegant or concise, here is one way to explode on all spaced then implode all elements except the last two: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6aCb6))

```
function implodeNotLastTwoElements($string) {
    $array = explode(' ', $string);
    array_splice($array, 0, -2, implode(' ', array_slice($array, 0, -2)));
    return $array;
}

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo json_encode(implodeNotLastTwoElements($string)) . "\n";
}
```

Or ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v7UGc))

```
function implodeNotLastTwoElements($string) {
    $array = explode(' ', $string);
    return [implode(' ', array_slice($array, 0, -2))] + array_slice($array, -3);
}
```

These non-regex approaches are iterating/scanning over the data 4 times versus regex only scanning the input string once and directly creating the desired result. The decision between regex or non-regex is a no-brainer for me in this case.